# I can't add Vue page transition with inertia js in vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs3, laravel-8, inertiajs

The transition Does not work in inertia page . if add appLayout between transition tag . its working . but all content gives transition.

Dashboard.vue

```
<template>
<admin-layout>
    <h1>Admin Dashboard</h1>
</admin-layout>
</template>
```

adminLayout.vue

```
<section class="adminPanel" :style="contentStyle">
    <AdminSvg/>
    <header-admin :style="headerStyle"/>
    <transition name="slide-fade">
        <div class="content">
            <slot></slot>
        </div>
    </transition>
    <sidebar-admin :style="sidebarStyle"/>
</section>
```

app.blade.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/admin.css') }}">
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    @inertia
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a simple solution that can help.
In the Layout component, Use the $page.url of the current url as a key .

```
<transition name="fade" mode="out-in" appear>
     <div :key="$page.url">
          <slot  />
     </div>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 3):

Vue transition works when the element that is wrapped by the transition tag changes (inserted or removed). Since inertia uses the backend route, simulating a page change should help with this. - This is not optimal but it works!

```
<section class="adminPanel" :style="contentStyle">
    <AdminSvg/>
    <header-admin :style="headerStyle"/>
    <transition name="slide-fade">
        <div v-if="content-trigger" class="content">
            <slot></slot>
          

        </div>
    </transition>
        <sidebar-admin :style="sidebarStyle"/>
</section>
<style>
    /* durations and timing functions.*/
    .slide-fade-enter-active {
        transition: all .5s ease;
    }
    .slide-fade-leave-active {
        transition: all .8s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
    }
    .slide-fade-enter, .slide-fade-leave-to
        /* .slide-fade-leave-active below version 2.1.8 */ {
        transform: translateX(10px);
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                content-trigger:false
            }
        },
        mounted(){
            this.content-trigger = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Working!... Just to mention that "content-trigger" is not a valid value (contentTrigger or something...)